# How to execute a file that is located in $PATH

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to execute a `hallo_word.sh` that is stored at `~/bin` from this script that is stored at my `~/Desktop`. I have made both scripts executable. But all the time I get the problem message. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh

clear
dir="$PATH"
read -p "which file you want to execute" fl
echo ""
for fl in $dir
do
    if [ -x "$fl" ]
    then
        echo "executing=====>"
        ./$fl
    else
        echo "Problem"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Should you be using `~/bin` or `$HOME/bin` in place of `/bin`, and similarly with `/Desktop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line has two problems:

```
for fl in $dir
```

1. $PATH is colon separated, but `for` expects whitespace separated values. You can change that by setting the `IFS` variable. This changes the FIELD SEPARATOR used by tools like `for` and `awk`.
2. `$fl` contains the name of the file you want to execute, but you overwrite its value with the contents of $dir.

Fixed:

```
#!/bin/sh

clear
read -p "which file you want to execute" file
echo
IFS=:
for dir in $PATH ; do  
    if [ -x "$dir/$file" ]
    then
        echo "executing $dir/$file"
        exec "$dir/$file"
    fi
done
echo "Problem"
```

Comment: You might want to improve your answer by explaining the IFS separator variable and why it is so important to the working of this script.

Answer (score 0):

You could also be lazy and let a subshell handle it.

```
PATH=(whatever) bash command -v my_command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   # Problem, could not be found.
else
   # No problem
fi
```

There is no need to over-complicate things.

command(1) is a builtin command that allows you to check if a command exists.

Answer (score 0):

The PATH value contains all the directories in which executable files can be run *without* explicit qualification. So you can just call the command directly.

```
#!/bin/sh

clear
# r for raw input, e to use readline, add a space for clarity
read -rep "Which file you want to execute? " fl || exit 1
echo ""
"$fl" || { echo "Problem" ; exit 1 ; }
```

I quote the name as it could have spaces.

To test if the command exists before execution use type -p

```
#!/bin/sh

clear
# r for raw input, e to use readline, add a space for clarity
read -rep "Which file you want to execute? " fl || exit 1
echo ""
type -p "$fq" >/dev/null || exit 1
"$fl" || { echo "Problem" ; exit 1 ; }
```